# Prevent temporary files in git workdir

Tags: git

I'm using git on a folder in a synchronized folder (Google Drive File Stream, G:).
the `.git` is a file linking to a location at a normal disk, (C:).

I've noticed that git is creating temporary files: `master`, `index` and `config`.

Because of the nature of Google Drive these files are not deleted correctly, generating annoying copies.

```
...    
config (110)
config (111)
index
index (1)
index (2)
...
master
master (1)
...
```

These are not files in the `.git` folder but in the workdir.

Is there a way to tell git not to work with temporary files in the workdir?

**All in G:**

As comparison a git repo completely located within G:, gitdir and workdir, works fine without creating these leftovers.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way around this.

> I'm using git on a folder in a synchronized folder (Google Drive) ...

Basically, the rule is: don't do that.  Git does not play well with these things (Google Drive, Dropbox, Virtualbox shared folders, etc).  Git *must* create temporary files in the work-tree because it uses / depends-on the atomicity of `rename` operations to control state.  These systems violate local-file-system rename atomicity rules, and therefore break Git.

It does *sometimes* work, and when it does, it may be OK to put up with the oddities.  (Setting some of the index options can sometimes help somewhat, e.g.,  `core.trustctime=false`, `core.ignoreStat=true`.)  But it cannot be made 100% reliable.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a Windows-specific Git bug; but Git certainly *tries* to keep files on the correct file system, using Linux-style naming systems, which should usually work under Windows naming systems as well. If you have the work tree and git directories separated, Git should be using temporary branch names in the Git directory!

Comment: In this case git creates the temporary file on G: and then moves it atomically to C:.  
  
As comparison I have another git repo that is completely located in Google Drive, .git directory and all, this one has no problem with leftover files probably because the files are moved rather than created and deleted.  
  
Would it make more sense to create the temporary files in the gitdir location since the files will be moved there?

Comment: (I answered your earlier comment so these came out of order.) Yes, that would make more sense, and should be how it should be working...

Comment: sorry about that, I had to remove one part of my comment and it was too old so I could only delete and repost it.